# Removing All Children

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having a little problem while developing a small `iOS` game. In `touchesbegan`, I add the `arc4random` called div to the screen, but in this method:

```
class TouchableSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        print("Touch")

        self.removeAllChildren()


    }
```

I want to remove the image from the screen again. This class get's called when the `node` itself is tapped. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move those touch handling methods into the parent and remove the specific child that is touched, or you can try:

```
self.removeFromParent()
```

Incidentally if `SKSpriteNode` is anything like `UIView` - you'll want to implement all four touch handling methods even if you don't need them all.